# for which values of $x,\,$ $I_x = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{(u\cos u - sin u)\cos ux}{u^3} \, du = 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I could prove that for $x = 1$ it's $0$

in fact if you compute the fourier transform of $f(x) =(1-x^2) \chi_{[-1,1]}$ you get $\hat{f}(u) =4\frac{\sin u - u\cos u}{u^3}$

on the one hand we have : 
$$I_1 = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{(u\cos u - sin u)\cos u}{u^3} \, du$$

and on the other hand we have $ \mathcal{F}[\frac{\delta(x-1)+\delta(x+1)}{2}] = \frac{1}{2} [e^{iu}+e^{-iu}] = \cos u$

then by Plancherel theorem : $I_1 = K \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\delta(x-1)+\delta(x+1)}{2}(1-x^2) \chi_{[-1,1]}dx = \frac{K}{2}[0+0] = 0$

any ideas which other values of $x$ may give the same result ?

Comment: $I(x)=0$ ,for: $x\leq -1\lor x\geq 1$

Comment: **HINT:**
Use the Fourier Inverse Theorem and evaluate the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (k^2-1)\text{rect}(k/2)e^{-ikx}\,dk=\int_{-1}^1 (k^2-1)e^{-ikx}\,dk$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mc{I} \equiv {1 \over 2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\bracks{u\cos\pars{u} - \sin\pars{u}}\cos\pars{ux} \over u^{3}}\,\dd u:\ {\Large ?}}$.

\begin{align}
\mc{I} & \equiv {1 \over 2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\bracks{u\cos\pars{u} - \sin\pars{u}}\cos\pars{ux} \over u^{3}}\,\dd u =
{1 \over 2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bracks{-\int_{0}^{1}t\,\sin\pars{ut}\,\dd t}{\cos\pars{u\verts{x}} \over u}\,\dd u
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}t\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{\bracks{t + \verts{x}}u} + \sin\pars{\bracks{t - \verts{x}}u} \over u}\,\dd u\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}t\bracks{%
\mrm{sgn}\pars{t + \verts{x}}\pi + \mrm{sgn}\pars{t - \verts{x}}\pi}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] &=
-\,{1 \over 4}\,\pi\bracks{%
{1 \over 2} +\int_{0}^{1}t\,\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{t - \verts{x}}\,\dd t}
\end{align}

---

Then,
\begin{align}
\mc{I} & \equiv {1 \over 2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\bracks{u\cos\pars{u} - \sin\pars{u}}\cos\pars{ux} \over u^{3}}\,\dd u
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 4}\,\pi\bracks{%
{1 \over 2} + \int_{0}^{1}\bracks{t > \verts{x} }t\,\dd t -
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{t < \verts{x}}t\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 4}\,\pi\bracks{%
{1 \over 2} + \bracks{0 < \verts{x} < 1}\int_{\verts{x}}^{1}t\,\dd t -
\bracks{0 < \verts{x} < 1}\int_{0}^{\verts{x}}t\,\dd t -
\bracks{\verts{x} > 1}\int_{0}^{1}t\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 4}\,\pi\bracks{%
{1 \over 2} + \bracks{0 < \verts{x} < 1}\pars{{1 \over 2} - {1 \over 2}\,x^{2}} -
\bracks{0 < \verts{x} < 1}{1 \over 2}\,x^{2} - \bracks{\verts{x} > 1}
{1 \over 2}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 4}\,\pi\bracks{%
{1 \over 2} + \bracks{0 < \verts{x} < 1}\pars{{1 \over 2} - x^{2}} -
\bracks{\verts{x} > 1}{1 \over 2}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{1 \over 4}\,\pi\bracks{0 < \verts{x} < 1}\pars{x^{2} - 1}}
\end{align}

[image]